# DLLImport Side-By-Side Error

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I'm using a DLLImport and getting a side-by-side configuration error. I tried debugging it with sxstrace.exe and this is the error it shows:

```
ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
```

The dll I'm trying to invoke is pHash.dll found here: http://www.phash.org/download/

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Note the message: **Debug** CRT.  You are using the DLL you found in the Debug folder.  That requires that you have the correct version of Visual Studio installed, VS2008 (version 9.0).  Clearly you are using another version.  Use the DLL from the Release folder instead.

Comment: @HansPassant That's exactly what I thought so I retried it making sure I was using the Release folder but I still get the exact same problem.

Comment: Ugh, they built it wrong.  The release build asks both the release and the debug CRT.  Throw this away, move to something else.